# Quick view of availability from 40 different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have 40 locations (40 sheets) in a workbook.  Each sheet shows days of week (across) and Time `12:00am` to `11:30pm` down in half hour increments (basically a 24/7 Schedule).  As time is booked at different locations, I am trying to create a quick view to show what times/days a location is available.  I have the actual range for filling in appointments as a named field on all 40 sheets, each with a unique name, the day - rows (4) are always visible as well as the rows showing the times.  They are locked ( rows 1-4 and Cols A and B are frozen.)
Now my problem.  I have a sheet with the same layout as the 40, but I want this one particular sheet to give me a quick overview of what times on what days are available where.  I created a macro to find all the blank (null) cells on each worksheet, but I can't seem to get a consolidated view of all them in one place. 
Can I do this with Excel/VBA?  I have forms created on this consolidated sheet so that the user can select the location to go to when they know whats available where.  I am just having trouble showing a quick view of availability.
ex... Loc1, loc2, loc3 are booked from 12:00am through 1:30am, but the remaining locations  loc4...loc40 are available at that time on Sunday, but that same time is booked Monday through Friday at 7 different locations leaving 33 available to book that time.  That time slot is available on Saturday at all locations, so Saturday should list all 40 locations. I have even tried setting it up as a chart with different color lines for the locations, but I'm not getting the results I want. I'm doing something wrong and not sure what.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is not easy. What is in a time slot to indicate it's booked? text or number? It is possible to construct a formula that would give you the first available sheet; returning all would probably take VBA. Seems to me you couldn't see all of the sheets listed if they were all in the same cell as a text list.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional formatting might be an easier option

Use something like `=IF('Name of sheet'!B2="","Not Booked","Booked")`

`B2` would be the cell that corresponds to the cell in your overview, then just auto-fill it across or down, just need to change the `'Name of sheet'` for each line you need. Once you've done that go into conditional formatting and set the sheet to display cells with not booked one color and booked a different one.